# Is it possible to cast my google data studio reports to a tv with chromecast?

Tags: chromecast, looker-studio

Has anyone tried (yet) to cast a google data studio reporting to a tv with a chromecast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Chrome to access Data Studio, then you can cast the tab by clicking the vertical ellipses icon in the top-right, then choosing cast. This works like casting any other tab.